# Java GUI resize issue

Tags: java, user-interface, resize

I have never actually built a GUI that is resizeable. I have always used "**JFrame.resizeable(false)**".

This time however, I wanted to try out some pixel manipulation with BufferedImage. I wanted to resize the image and see how the pixels reacted. However it didn't go as expected. The animation just stopped and doesn't stretch the window as it should?

See this [GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoFJC.jpg).

I have two classes in my project. One is a timer - so I can update once 1/60 second. The other is just the window. These are called **"Update"** and **"Window"**.

**Update code:**

```
if(render) {    //Render
            frames++;
            window.clear();

            render = false;
        }
```

**Window code:**

```
public class Window extends Canvas {

//Variabler
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
int width = 1000;           //Gör så den kan resiza.. pls
int height = 1000;          //Gör så den kan resiza.. pls
int i = 0;
private JFrame window;
private BufferStrategy bs;
private Graphics g;
private BufferedImage image;
//----


public Window() {

    window = new JFrame();

    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    window.add(this,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    window.setResizable(true);
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null); //Sätter den i mitten.
    window.getPreferredSize();  //Set preferred size
    window.pack();  //Set size for real




    //Bufferstrategy
    this.createBufferStrategy(2);   
    bs = this.getBufferStrategy();

    g = bs.getDrawGraphics();


    window.setVisible(true);    //Visa window



}
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {   
    return new Dimension(width,height);


}

public void clear() {   
    image = new BufferedImage(window.getWidth(),window.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB); 
    int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();   


        for(int x = 0; x < pixels.length; x++) {
            pixels[x] = i++;        //Makes an effect

        }


        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, window.getWidth(), window.getHeight(), null);



    bs.show();
}
}
```

I now wonder - why does it act this way? What is wrong with my code? If this has already been posted (I didn't find a similar post), feel free to send me to that post :)

Thanks!

**EDIT**

**MRE:**

In the loop it renders every 1/60 of a second and runs this code:

```
if(render) {    //Render
        frames++;
        window.clear();

        render = false;
    }
```

The window.clear() function is in another class:

```
public void clear() {   
image = new BufferedImage(window.getWidth(),window.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB); 
int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();   


    for(int x = 0; x < pixels.length; x++) {
        pixels[x] = i++;        //Makes an effect

    }


    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, window.getWidth(), window.getHeight(), null);



bs.show();
}
```

This method is used to clear the screen, however, at the moment I use it as an animation thingy. I do this by adding 1 to the i variable (my int color value). For clearing 0 is optimal.

Comment: I wish you wouldn't re-use existing class names it can be very confusing.  https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Window.html

Comment: A correct layout with resizability is hard.  Most people re-use existing code.  For example, GroupLayout and SpringLayout.  https://netbeans.org/features/java/swing.html

Comment: I noticed that as well, will change that to next time :) @markspace

Comment: I'll look into that, I am using BorderLayout as of now! @markspace

Comment: I changed from BorderLayout.CENTER to SpringLayout.WEST. It only works in the direction WEST however. I want it to stretch the entire screen no matter direction.. If i resize it upwards it disappears as in the GIF for example.

Comment: Is it a way to make it work in all directions?

Comment: BorderLayout.CENTER is the easiest to use to dynamically resize a component. Don't bother with the other layouts (SpringLayout or GroupLayout) which are generally only used by IDE generated code. The layout manager is not the issue for your code. I also don't know why you are using a BufferStrategy when you can just do custom painting in the paintComponent() method of a JPanel.  Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I know I can use paintComponent. The thing is that I didn't know that they had the function to affect individual pixels. So I did it this way instead.. which I guess was wrong. I kind of struggle when to use JPanel or Canvas. However, I will make an MRE for you! I will make an "Edit" section.

Comment: I heard about this way of doing it when I read about gameEngines. I do not know why the  guy preferred this way..

Comment: *I didn't know that they had the function to affect individual pixels.* - a BufferedImage is a BufferedImage whether you use it in a BufferStrategy or a JPanel. That is not an "MRE". We can't copy/paste/compile and test.

Comment: Yeah I mean, I didn’t know Graphics had a setRGB() function. Does JPanel have a build in buffertstrategy? Or why would you choose JPanel above Bufferstrategy? I know paintComponent has one build in.

Comment: Graphics does NOT have a setRGB() method. That is a method of the BufferedImage.   Whether you use setRGB() on the BufferedImage or use the code you currently have is irrelevant. Both methods manipulate the BufferedImage so it can be used in the drawImage(…) method. Swing is double buffered by default. You don't do anything special. I have never used a BufferStrategy. All Swing component do the custom painting in its paintComponent() method.

Comment: Oh am I that tired that I mixed those up? Oh well.. okay - that’s useful. The Teo solutions basically does the same thing.. I wonder why some prefer the one I use.. anyways this doesnt explain the resize issue does it? I can’t figure out whats going on there. When i did it Will springlayout I got it working - but you told me to use BorderLayout?

Comment: Found this link: http://www.jamesgames.org/resources/double_buffer/double_buffering_and_active_rendering.html and did a quick read. Seems to be helpful. Even has a section on stretching the Graphics as the frame resizes. Any layout manager that dynamically resizes the component should work. A component added to the BorderLayout.CENTER will automatically be resized horizontally and vertically to fill the frame with no other special constraint. When you use SpringLayout or GroupLayout you need to set multiple different constraints, which people usually get wrong.

Comment: Hey! Sorry for making you wait, got into some other work sorry! I rewrote the code and implemented JPanel with paintComponent instead. Didn't even need a border layout. So something went wrong with the painting process when using the canvas. Btw, where  can I read  about canvas vs jPanel and when to not use paintComponent? I read about the canvas vs jPanel in the link you provided. However he didn't mention it really that much. Thanks!